# Implementing Search Functionality in Firebase

Tags: android, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement search functionality in which the results are filtered from the person's email & their username.

[image: Firebase Database Structure]

Suggestions are displayed in a list using RecyclerView.

I'm completely dependent on Firebase for my backend as of now.

How should I go about it.

Note : There have been questions asked before too regarding implementation of search in Firebase but they are all outdated as Firebase supports a lot more features now.

Comment: Firebase has indeed expanded. But searching the realtime database is still the same as before.

Comment: Can you elaborate.

Comment: This is the approach I typically use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34902598/3268303